# GameHelper crashing at application start

Tags: java, android, google-play, libgdx, google-play-services

**So, I guess it'd help to say that I'm using LibGDX.**

**Code:**

```
package com.fmeg.tapout.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.applifier.impact.android.ApplifierImpact;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.fmeg.tapout.ActionResolver;
import com.fmeg.tapout.TapoutGame;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.GameHelperListener;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication
    implements GameHelperListener, ActionResolver {

    private static final String EVERPLAY_GAME_ID = "14234";

    private GameHelper gameHelper;

    public AndroidLauncher() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

        ApplifierImpact.setDebugMode(false);
        ApplifierImpact.setTestMode(false);
        ApplifierImpact impact = new ApplifierImpact((Activity)this, EVERPLAY_GAME_ID);
        ApplifierImpact.instance.changeActivity(this);

        gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
        gameHelper.setup(this);

        initialize(new TapoutGame(impact, this), config);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
//      gameHelper.onStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
//      gameHelper.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
//      gameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void unlockAchievement(String achievementID) {
        Games.Achievements.unlock(gameHelper.getApiClient(), achievementID);
    }

    @Override
    public void achivementProgress(String achievementID, int progression) {
        Games.Achievements.increment(gameHelper.getApiClient(), achievementID, progression);
    }

    @Override
    public void submitScoreToLeaderboard(String leaderboardID, int score) {
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(), leaderboardID, score);
    }

    @Override
    public void displayLeaderboard(String leaderboardID) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), leaderboardID), 101);
    }

    @Override
    public void shareScore(String challenge, int score) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I managed to get "+score+" taps during the " + challenge + " while playing Tap Out! How fast are you? Challenge the world. #FMEGTapout Download Now! http://bit.ly/FMEGTapout");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }

}
```

The above code compiles and runs fine, however as soon as you attempt to use one of the google play services, such as updating a score or an achievement you get this error:

```
05-24 01:19:11.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24280): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
05-24 01:19:11.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24280): java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
05-24 01:19:11.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24280):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.fq.a(Unknown Source)
05-24 01:19:11.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24280):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.b(Unknown Source)
05-24 01:19:11.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24280):    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.AchievementsImpl.unlock(Unknown Source)
05-24 01:19:11.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24280):    at com.fmeg.tapout.android.AndroidLauncher.unlockAchievement(AndroidLauncher.java:77)
05-24 01:19:11.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24280):    at com.fmeg.tapout.screens.GameOver.handleAchievements(GameOver.java:98)
05-24 01:19:11.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24280):    at com.fmeg.tapout.screens.GameOver.<init>(GameOver.java:36)
05-24 01:19:11.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24280):    at com.fmeg.tapout.screens.Tick.run(Play.java:85)
05-24 01:19:11.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24280):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Also in AndroidLauncher.java if you uncomment the following lines

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
```

//      gameHelper.onStart(this);
    }

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
```

//      gameHelper.onStop();
    }

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
```

//      gameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    }

The application will crash upon startup, and this is how it's supposed to be called anyway according to the references I've been using. The crash error shows:

```
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$h.b(Unknown Source)
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$h.a(Unknown Source)
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$b.eN(Unknown Source)
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
05-24 01:32:19.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25552):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

### https://github.com/TheInvader360/libgdx-gameservices-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial-libgdx-gameservices-android/src/com/theinvader360/tutorial/libgdx/gameservices/MainActivity.java

### https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks fine. However, since you are using `CLIENT_ALL` (meaning all Play Games services) you will need to add **both** of the following to your manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

The first is required to sign-in, and the second is required for cloud saves - which, even if you don't use it, you have requested access to with `CLIENT_ALL`.

This tripped me up as well because the second one is **only** mentioned under the Cloud Save section of the documentation.

If this does not fix your problem (i.e. you already have those in your manifest), the best place to start is the [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting) section of the documentation.

Also, to get full error logging you should enable the debug log for the game helper, as follows:

```
 gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
 gameHelper.setup(this);

 gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);   // add this (but only for debug builds)
```

Comment: Thanks! It runs now, however I can't sign in. The error being recieved is 05-24 15:22:37.829: D/GameHelper(11730): GameHelper: onActivityResult: req=RC_RESOLVE, resp=SIGN_IN_FAILED
05-24 15:22:37.829: D/GameHelper(11730): GameHelper: onAR: responseCode=SIGN_IN_FAILED, so giving up.
05-24 15:22:37.829: W/GameHelper(11730): disconnect() called when client was already disconnected.
05-24 15:22:37.949: D/GameHelper(11730): GameHelper: Notifying LISTENER of sign-in FAILURE (error)
 I'm going to check the troubleshooting docs now, but i figured i'd post it.

Comment: Those errors indicate that your code is working correctly, as it is receiving a response from the sign-in in your `onActivityResult`. The problem is mostly likely on the server side. Ensure that you have added your account to the test accounts (in the Game services console) and that you have specified the correct APP IDs.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help; I've finally got things working what seems like properly, however I've ran into one more problem. Image located here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wV3rf.jpg -- I've checked everything that I can; Including making a new application and going through the entire setup process again with google play under a new package name and application name, changing the app id and whatnot, but I still can't manage to get it working. Any advice would be appreciated while I continue to try to fix this. ** The SHA1 is matching correctly, I am a tester, and the client ID (App ID?) matches

Comment: Thanks man....I was stuck with the issue...I need to add two id in my manifest and voila