# Fatal Exception when beginUserInitiatedSignIn called

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services

My program works fine

```
  package com.mygdx.game.android;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.GameHelperListener;
import com.mygdx.game.I_interface;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameHelperListener{

    private Context context;
    private GameHelper gameHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("onCreate", "Inside onCreate");   



        context = AndroidLauncher.this;
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        myInterface = new AndroidLauncher();
        config.useWakelock = true;
        config.useAccelerometer = true;
        config.useCompass = false;
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        View gameView = initializeForView(new MyGdxGame(myInterface), config);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        layout.addView(gameView);
        setContentView(layout);

        if(gameHelper == null) {
            gameHelper = new GameHelper(this,GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
            gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);            
        }
        gameHelper.setup(this);

        //signin();
    }

    public void signin(){
        //Run this code on the main thread.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {      
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Check if user is signed in
                    try{
                        //if not, attempt to sign in
                        gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        //Handle errors with an alert box
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidLauncher.this); 
                        alert.setTitle("Unable to sign in");
                        alert.setMessage("The app was unable to sign in to G+. An error occured.");
                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
                        alert.show();
                    }
                }                  
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        gameHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    }
}
```

But as soon i call signin to start google playservices it shows fatal exception

```
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$h.b(Unknown Source)
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$h.a(Unknown Source)
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$b.eN(Unknown Source)
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
07-22 07:16:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4468):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I guess something is wrong in the procedure of my calls.
As no sample project is available for libgDx with latest version of google play services 
I am stuck really bad.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

solved it,
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841976/gamehelper-crashing-at-application-start?rq=1)

Actually I am using all all the client

```
if(gameHelper == null) {
            gameHelper = new GameHelper(this,GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
            gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);            
        }
```

so thats why I need to add app id for gamestate and games in my manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

And Voila, it is done

Comment: Hey Nipun, can you share the complete tutorial or step by step guide, for adding leaderboards in a game. it's been 10 days that my app is completed, and just leaderboards are remaining, thank you in advance.